# ImportError: cannot import name 'TFTModel' from 'darts.models'

Tags: python, libraries

I receive the error message
"ImportError: cannot import name 'TFTModel' from 'darts.models'" when trying to import the atribute "TFTmodel" from darts using the line

```
from darts.models import TFTModel
```

I have tried using "pip install statsforecast==0.6.0" however that leads to me not being able to use darts since the current darts version isn't compatible with that statsforecast version, and when i try to downgrade the darts version i get a error with pandas that just leads me to upgrade my darts version which puts me in a loop

The versions im using are
darts 0.22.0

startsforecast 1.3.2

Windows 10 x64 version 21H2

python 3.9.13

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly mean there is no TFTModel in that version. Have you checked documentation and other versions?

Comment: i just looked it up and it seems to exist so i dont think thats the case

Comment: @CaioNavarro can you send me the documentation? I'll try it myself.

Comment: https://unit8co.github.io/darts/generated_api/darts.models.forecasting.tft_model.html this is the link for the darts TFT model

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.
As seen in the documentation it says it's in `darts.models.forcasting`, so try:

```
from darts.models.forcasting import TFTModel
```

Comment: that results in "ImportError: cannot import name 'TFTModel' from 'darts.models.forecasting'"

Comment: Really odd. I don't know why this happens. Have you tried importing an entire thing if you only imported partial of the module?

Comment: i have not how would i go about that?

Comment: You could also use the torchforcasting module if this one doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this

```py
from darts.models.forecasting.tft_model import TFTModel
```